# How to disable searchable ability after displaying the options in Select element(react-select)?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am passing options asynchronously to select element.Anyway i would like to have a condition to check how many options are being passed.If options are <=10, then  search should be disabled,if options are >10 then search should be enabled. here is my code,

```
render() {
    var getOptions = (input, callback) => {
        axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                                  response.data.map(function(a){
                                                      a.value = a.id;
                                                      a.label = a.id;
                                                    });
                   callback(null,{options :response.data,complete : true});
            })
    } 

    return (
        <div className="col-md-6">      
          <div>Select List:</div>
             <Select.Async
                  loadOptions={getOptions}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.value}
                />
        </div>
    );
}
```

By using "searchable" attribute we can either enable or disable the select component. But i do not know how to this based on some condition. Could any body give any suggestion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better try following,

```
axios.get(url_large).then(function (response) {
            response.data.map(function(a){                                               
                                           a.value = a.id;
                                           a.label = a.title;
                                         });
                    this.setState({ options : response.data }) ;
                    if(response.data.length <= 10) {
                        this.setState({ disable : false }) ;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.setState({ disable : true }) ;
                    }
                    callback(null,{options :response.data,complete : true});

        }.bind(this));
}
```

here 'disable' is a state value which you have to define first in constructor and then pass it to your 'Select' attribute 'searchable'.